# How to load database of a user in a another activity(profile activity) after login success? i am trying to create a profile page

Tags: java, php, android, xml, android-studio

I have created a login activity and it's working fine, after login success. "profile" activity is opening but there i want to load logged in user's details which i've stored in mysql database. can anyone help me how to do it.?

My Backgroundworker.java file

```js
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://192.168.43.59/login.php";
        String register_url = "http://192.168.43.59/register.php";
        if (type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String username = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL (login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("pass_word","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (type.equals("register")){
            try {
                String name = params[1];
                String surname = params[2];
                String username = params[3];
                String password = params[4];
                String address = params[5];
                String pinArea_code = params[6];
                String email = params[7];
                String phone = params[8];
                URL url = new URL (register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("reg_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("reg_surname","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(surname,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("reg_user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("reg_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("reg_add","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(address,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("reg_pin","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pinArea_code,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("reg_mail","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("reg_ph","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phone,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
        if(result.contains("login success")){
            Intent ilogin = new Intent(context, Profile.class);
            context.startActivity(ilogin);
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        } else if (result.contains("Account Created")){
            Intent iregister = new Intent(context, about_us.class);
            context.startActivity(iregister);
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

My MainActivity.Java file

```js
package com.quickhomeservice.qhs.astudio;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText UsernameET, PasswordET;
    //String username, password;
    private TextView button_reg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UsernameET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
        PasswordET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        //ab.setLogo(R.mipmap.logo_mini86);
        ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        OnClickButtonListner();
    }

    public void OnLogin (View view){
        String username = UsernameET.getText().toString();
        String password = PasswordET.getText().toString();
        String type = "login";

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
    }

    public void OnClickButtonListner(){
        button_reg=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_link);
        button_reg.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.quickhomeservice.qhs.astudio.registraion_form");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.Contact_id:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, contact_us.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                return true;
            case R.id.About_id:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, about_us.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my login.php file

```html
<?php
require "conn.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["pass_word"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from user_data where username like '$user_name' and password like '$user_pass';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
echo "login success";
}
else{
echo "login failed";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php file, you can echo the result of your query as a JSON instead of just echoing "Log in success", since your query selects all columns of a table that match the given condition.

Php example:

```
<?php

require "conn.php";

$user = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


$response["user_data"] = array();

//Use mysqli_prepare to secure yourself from sql injection.

$query = $conn->prepare("Select * from user_data where username = ? and password = ?");
$query->bind_param("ss", $user, $password);
$query->execute();

$result = $query->get_result();

// check if the query returned a row (which means success)
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    $response["message"] = "Log in success";

    $getUserData = $conn->prepare(// your query here where username = ?);
    $getUserData->bind_param("s", $user);
    $getUserData->execute();

    $getResult = $getUserData->get_result();

    while($row_data = $getResult->fetch_assoc()){

        array_push($response["user_data"] = $row_data);

    }

    echo json_encode($response);


}
else{

    // your else statement.

}

?>
```

and parse it in java.

Comment: can you please give an example editing my php and java file which i've shared with you?

Comment: Thanks mate... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create static final Strings in your login class, and fetch the database user information to these when you authenticate the user.

Later you can create an instance of your login class whenever you need to access your user data.

Comment: I am new to scripting bro, i didn't get it properly, can you create an example file if possible?